# Nested SQL Left Join with Pivot and Unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

```
SELECT [Table], Facility_Code,
   ISNULL([1],0) AS [1],
   ISNULL([2],0) AS [2],
   ISNULL([3],0) AS [3],
   ISNULL([4],0) AS [4],
   ISNULL([5],0) AS [5],
   ISNULL([6],0) AS [6],
   ISNULL([7],0) AS [7],
   ISNULL([8],0) AS [8],
   ISNULL([9],0) AS [9],
   ISNULL([10],0) AS [10],
   ISNULL([11],0) AS [11],
   ISNULL([12],0) AS [12],
FROM(
    SELECT 'TotalItemsProduced' AS [Table],
    L.Facility_Code,
    [Month],
    Total_Item_Count
FROM production L
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
         Facility_Code,
         COUNT(DISTINCT(item_nbr)) AS Total_Item_Count,
         MONTH(datetime) AS MONTH
    FROM item
    WHERE YEAR(datetime) = 2018
    GROUP BY Facility_Code, MONTH(datetime)
 )R
 ON L.Facility_Code = R.Facility_Code
)T
PIVOT(MAX(Total_Item_Count) FOR [Month] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], 
[7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])) AS PVT
```

I wrote this code, got this far, now I have to unpivot this table. I am not sure how to nest in the unpivot function because the left join is sort of throwing me off.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (SQL Server?)

Comment: Syntax error at: `COUNT(DISTINCT(item_nbr) AS Total_Item_Count,`.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server

Comment: `DISTINCT`  is not a function. Skip those redundant parentheses to make the code clearer, i.e. do `COUNT(DISTINCT item_nbr) AS Total_Item_Count,`.

Comment: @TP89 . . . Your question would be much clearer if you provided sample data and desired results.  It is probably better to leave out the pivoting and just ask one question for the full transformation.